# Spring Authorization Server. What's the difference between RegistredClient and UserDetails?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, authorization-server

On their Getting started guide, [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html), Spring Authorization Server have a piece of code where they declare two beans - UserDetailsService and RegistredClientRepository. I wanted to play around retrieving some tokens from the server. I tried using postman. Within authorization tab I entered the values from the guide:
[image]

it answered with:

[image]

So then I tried inputting client credentials from RegistredClientRepository entry:

[image]

And it worked.

So my question is: what is the purpose of UserDetails and RegistredClient being both available in this case?

And another little bit off-topic question: if I create my own authorization server for client credentials flow between my servers, how does every server know that token belongs to legitimate server and not to some attacker who can just register with needed clientId if there's an opportunity? How can resource server actually verify that token owner is the server it trusts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in oauth2, a "client" is an application which users might use to interface with some service - for example something like an App people can install on their phones or a web application.

Most oauth2 implementations have "scopes" (basically defined sets of access rights). Clients (client applications) are registered with some metadata (name, author, ...), a set of scopes they might use and some details to improve security - like "where is that application hosted" (in form of "which redirect URIs are valid"), client ID and client secret.

Depending on the oauth2 flow chosen, your App needs to prove being **that app** by some means - e.g. by having a valid combination of client ID and redirect URI or by doing HTTP basic auth with their client ID as username and client secret as password when exchanging a "code" for a "token".

All this was about clients - now about users: they are what you would expect, the users of a service - like you and me are users on Stackoverflow.com

> And another little bit off-topic question: if I create my own
> authorization server for client credentials flow between my servers,
> how does every server know that token belongs to legitimate server and
> not to some attacker who can just register with needed clientId if
> there's an opportunity? How can resource server actually verify that
> token owner is the server it trusts?

for this you could either use a form of signed tokens (look at e.g. JWT) or store the currently valid tokens per user in a database reachable by all your servers - both have pro's and con's, tokens in a database are easier to revoke, while signed tokens don't require you to store any state in a database (which can be expensive in big distributed systems)

**Update - OP actually wants to do server-to-server authentication, see comments below**

Server-to-server authentication can often work very well without any extra authentication server, in cases where your parties a less dynamic - like when you always have "those three servers" and they don't come and go very often.

In such cases, using a simple token is probably better and easier than using an oauth2 stack. Each server could just have a list of randomly generated strings in its config file, let's call this "the set of valid tokens" and also knows which token to send when communicating with a specific other server. When a request comes in, the server checks if the given token is in its set of valid tokens - done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's almost clear, but still, let me challenge you with my example. I am going to use two different clients (probably sharing the same host, but are different processes). I've been advised to develop an authorization server to authorize Server A to access Server B's API. Of course, I could just create a client with specific clientId, and tell Server B that client with this clientId is the trusted one. But this approach is based on my **knowledge** that this clientId is trusted. The question is how do I programmatically get this knowledge?

Comment: Let's say I trust the authorization server. So I trust that information in JWTs it sends is legit. So should I just trust the authority of the authorization server and simply create needed client and tell resource server that this clientId is trusted? Should I be afraid of that someone could try attacking my authorization server by registering client faster than me?

Comment: Usually client IDs are generated on registering a client and are a random string and registering clients is a privileged operation for which you need to be authenticated and authorized to your auth server - so someone else quickly registering the client before you wouldn't be a problem, as they cannot choose the client ID.

what is your client? do you simply wish to authenticate server-to-server communication or are there any end users involved?

Comment: It's all coming together for me now. Yes, I wish to authenticate server-to-server as my beginning task. So based on your answer, I should just create an admin account at my authorization server, then create a registred client with certain clientId and then all tokens  that contain this clientId are guaranteed to be legit because only admin (who's trusted) could register this clientId, am I right?

Comment: And if I am right, please, edit the last paragraph of your answer so I can accept it ;) I am very grateful for your answers and hope you have a good time!

Comment: added some more to the answer for your current server-to-server use-case. Especially when you don't know oauth2 and/or the specific software stack already, using it for a case where it is not needed might be an unnecessary risk - static configured tokens are easier to implement and understand and work great in many server-to-server cases.

Comment: If you still want to use oauth2 for server-to-server communication, each server should probably be a client and a user, logging into the authentication server as user $itself, using the "app" $itself. Having the servers as users allows you to restrict specific requests on one server to specific other servers.

Comment: registering the client ID has nothing to do with retrieving the tokens - tokens are retrieved for a user-client pair - it's only usable by the client, but only has the access rights of the user it is for (and from that only the subset the client is allowed to use, too).

Do you know these "Log in with Google" buttons all over the internet? Such websites showing that button are a client, you are a user and when you click that button (and approve), a token is generated, granting that website to access Google in your name - Google as example for a service here

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. I can understand that static tokens are way easier to implement, but what do you mean by saying it's risky to implement dynamic ones? Since I am only using features of Spring framework, it's hard to tell whether I am creating any additional vulnerabilities.

Comment: In my opinion not knowing how to implement some sort of stuff is not a good excuse for a programmer, because we always have something we don't know but need to know. I now work as a junior backend developer and working on my first big project. So I try to guide myself using best practices. I was told that authorization server is crucial for scalability of an application, and it makes sense. If I ever need to develop a new service (which is likely, because I already have three), it won't be a cumbersome task - I will just need to add a new oauth client

Comment: The risks I meant are all in the area of not knowing the authentication stack very well, which could lead to bad configurations or usage of that - the less you understand a security-relevant thing, the more risky it is to use it. Of course you can only really learn it by using it - if that risk is relevant depends on your full use case, e.g. what could go wrong if authentication failed (nothing because hobby project, leak of your data, leak of customer data, attackers now controlling your servers, ...)

Comment: I see. So I'll take that into account. But anyway you gave me a precious insight I've been looking for. The question was really hard to google. Thank you

Comment: I guess I should write a blog post for this, to have something easier to google :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247582/discussion-between-littlefox-and-yuriy-kirel).